# How to put this element in the toolbar?

Tags: android, tabs, fragment

I've created my application with Navigation Drawer. 
In my Activity I put this code:

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
    {
        public void onDrawerOpened(View view)
        {
            super.onDrawerOpened(view);
        }
        public void onDrawerClosed(View v)
        {
            super.onDrawerClosed(v);
        }
    };
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    onNavigationItemSelected(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0));
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) 
    {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = null;
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Class fragmentClass=null;

    if (id == R.id.Home)
    {
      fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
      title="Home";

    }
    else if (id == R.id.Profile)
    {
      fragmentClass= ProfileFragment.class;
      title="Profile";
    }
    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,      fragment).commit();


    if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
    {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);


    return true;
}
```

now in the HomeFragment I want to put a tab in the bottom of the screen. So i put this code:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


public static TabLayout tabLayout;
public static ViewPager viewPager;
public static int int_items = 3 ;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);


    tabLayout = (TabLayout) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);


    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));


    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    });

    return inflatedView;

}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    /**
     * Return fragment with respect to Position .
     */

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        switch (position){
            case 0 : return new SearchFragment();
            case 1 : return new CardFragment();
            case 2 : return new MapFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int getCount() {

        return int_items;

    }
```

But finally I obtain this result:

[image]

I want to do this:

1. put this tablayout in the toolbar
2. put this in the bottom of the
   screen

How could I do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `TabLayout` at the bottom of the screen, you don't have to actually put it in the toolbar. If it is specific to that Fragment it should stay in there. In your layout try doing this:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

Depending on the parent container that should work, then you just hook it up to the `ViewPager` you create to handle each tab. If it is a `RelativeLayout` use `alignParentBottom` instead of `layout_gravity`.

Also if you want it to disappear like it would when you scroll on other apps, you can still do `app:layout_anchor="@id/items_list"` and `app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"` then attach the behaviors to get it to slide out on scroll. It doesn't actually require it to be in a `AppBarLayout`.

Also remove the padding/margin from your base view.